# geemap doesn't display attributions

Tags: python, leaflet, google-earth-engine, folium, geemap

Is it normal that `geemap` doesn't display attributions in my notebook? Is there a way to add them?

I'm running :

```py
import geemap

m = geemap.Map(center=[40,-100], zoom=4)
m.add_basemap('CartoDB.Positron')
m
```

And I get this map
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771914/force-geemap-to-display-attributions

Comment: I'm completely fine with deleting one of them, where do you think this question should live, here or on SO ?

Comment: After re-reading https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, I'm not sure. It's a programming problem (so, StackOverflow) but it's about a package specific for GIS (so, GIS.se) :-/

Comment: I have pretty much the same amount of people seeing it here or there, so I'm deleting the SO one. not cross-posted anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### default behaviour

This [issue](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap/issues/111) has been patched by the owner of the repo this afternoon.

now the attributions are set by default on the `geemap.Map`.

#### Manually customize controls

If you're using custom controls you can add it manually through:

```py
import geemap
m = geemap.Map(center=[40,-100], zoom=4)
m.clear_controls()
m.add_control(geemap.AttributionControl(position='bottomright'))
```